# Compile error: member with constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

struct AABB
{
    union {
        struct { glm::vec3 pMin, pMax; };
        struct { float x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1; };
    };
};
```

[Try it.](https://godbolt.org/z/z6E433)

I'm guessing it's not allowed because `glm::vec3` has a contructor. What's the alternative?

There is this similar question but it's not the same: [constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate, string in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031424/constructor-not-allowed-in-anonymous-aggregate-string-in-struct)

Comment: one solution proposed in the related post is to use pointers to types/classes instead of the concrete type

Comment: Possibly off topic but it looks like you're trying to type-pun through a union.  That will generally result in undefined behaviour in C++.

Comment: @G.M Oh, true, I forgot about that :/

Comment: Isn't that what GLM itself also does? (https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/4137519418a933e5863eea7c3ac53890ae7faf9d/glm/detail/type_vec3.hpp#L56) Is it really UB, if order, align and size equal?